# NavBar collapse not working with ng-include

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have 3 html pages.
1. Index.html 
2. MasterPagenvarBar.html
3. ContentPage.html

** In Index.html calling MasterpagenavBar.html and ContentPage.html .below is my code.

```
  <body ng-app="theapp">  
        <div ng-include="'../Views/MasterPageNavBar.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'../Views/ContentPage.html'"></div>
    </body>
```

** In MasterpageNavBar.html Collapse functionality(data-toggle) is working fine , when i run alone this page.

When i combine MasterPage.NavBar.html and ContentPage.html in 'Index.html" collapse  is not working. May be Contentpage.html not allowing space to show navbar content when user clicks on toggle Icon button.

Here is my "MasterPageNavBar.html" code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Collapse.JS"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>AngularJS Tutorial</h3> 
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#mynavbar" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a data-ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a data-ui-sref="contactus">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Login/SignUp</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is "ContentPage.html" code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/main.js"></script>

    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="container" data-ng-app="theapp">
    <div class="well">
        <header>Content Page</header>
        <div data-ui-view=""></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```